# How to remove a Property from SoapObject?

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am receiving a SoapObject with 2 properties having the same name. I want to remove one of them from the Object, and I am not sure how do I achieve that.

The purpose is, I actually want to read both the properties like:
soapObject.getProperty("PropertyName");

I have successfully tried using a for loop:
for(int i = 0; i < soapObject.getPropertyCount(); i++)
    soapObject.getProperty(atIndex);

But, it doesn't serve my purpose. I need to retrieve them by name. So, how can I retrieve both?

I tried calling the method twice, but it returns the same values twice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried with the for each loop? It allows you to access both the key and, consequently, the value.
Here you can find an example from which you can start:

```
for (K key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + "=" + map.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood the problem statement correctly
you can remove the duplicate soap object by one of the following methods,(but first add it into an arraylist)

1. Using Iterator
2. Using LinkedHashSet. A better way (both time
   complexity and ease of implementation wise) is to remove duplicates from an ArrayList is to convert it into a Set that does not allow duplicates
3. Using Java 8 Stream.distinct() You can use the distinct() method from the Stream API